# Message After Redirecting VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I redirect the user to the same page but I would like for a popup message stating the error. I cannot use messagebox because it does not work in the app. I tried Response.Write did not work. I have put a label with the error message but I do not know how to make it appear when the page reloads because of the error.

Could I use page_load, and IsPostBack? If so, how can I tell that it is reloading because of the catch error? Or if you know a better way...

Idea I have when error happens about the page_load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    //This could be in IsPostBack if needed.
    If (the catch error happen) then 
     Show Label next to the button.
    EndIf

    If Page.IsPostBack Then


    End If
```

My code to redirect the user when error happens:

```
ElseIf e.CommandName = "Remove" Then
        Try
            Dim dto As PDto = MyPage.DelegateP.GetPDtoByPrimaryKey(Me.OPId)
        If dto.Id > 0 Then
            dto.LUser = MyPage.LUser
            MyPage.DelegateP.DeletePDto(dto)
        End If
        Me.PanelOtherPForm.Style("display") = "none"
        Me.FormViewDetails.Style("display") = "none"
        Me.CurrentOPId = 0
        Me.Repeater1.DataBind()
        BubbleOPChanged()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Default.aspx?i={0}&c={1}", MyPage.DtoPage.PageID, Me.CId))
        End Try
```

Comment: What I end up doing is not to redirect the user, and just have a label to show up next to the delete button.

Comment: Would you prefer a pop up solution? If so, have you had a chance to try the code I gave you below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `MsgBox` won't work when you publish your app to the server but you can make a pop up message with client side script. In this example, I force an error to happen and show you the error message in a pop up message that should run fine on your server.

```
Try
    'Force an error to happen for testing
    Dim test As Integer
    test = "test"
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim errorText As String
    errorText = Replace(ex.Message, """", "")   'Script will error if we don't replace double quotes
    errorText = Replace(errorText, "'", "")     'Replace single quotes, too
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "testAlert", "alert('" + errorText + "');", True)
End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

You could attach an error code to the URL as a parameter when you redirect.
Then on page load, check if the parameter is there and deal with it as you see fit.